Measuring cache line latency
I want to measure the latency to access one element of a cache line.
I have an struct with a next index and padding to have a length of a cache line size (64 bytes in my arch).
Then, an array of N structs randomly sorted.
Here's the code (based on Chips and Cheese code):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>



#define L1_SIZE 32 * 1024
#define L2_SIZE 256 * 1024
#define L3_SIZE 12288 * 1024


#define CACHE_LINE_SIZE_BYTES 64
#define U64_PER_CACHE_LINE CACHE_LINE_SIZE_BYTES / 8

int default_test_sizes[37] = { 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 192, 256, 384, 512, 600, 768, 1024, 1536, 2048,
                               3072, 4096, 5120, 6144, 8192, 10240, 12288, 16384, 24567, 32768, 65536, 98304,
                               131072, 262144, 393216, 524288, 1048576 };

typedef struct cache_line {
    uint64_t next;
    uint64_t padding[ (CACHE_LINE_SIZE_BYTES - sizeof(cache_line*)) / sizeof(uint64_t) ];

} cache_line;


double runTest(uint64_t size_lines, uint32_t iterations) {
    uint64_t size = (size_lines * CACHE_LINE_SIZE_BYTES) / sizeof(cache_line);
    cache_line *cache_lines = (cache_line*) malloc(size * sizeof(cache_line));

    if (!cache_lines) {
        std::cout << "Error on malloc" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cache_lines[i].next = i;
    }

    uint32_t iter = size;
    while(iter > 1) {
        iter -= 1;
        int j = iter - 1 == 0 ? 0 : rand() % (iter - 1);
        uint64_t tmp = cache_lines[iter].next;
        cache_lines[iter].next = cache_lines[j].next;
        cache_lines[j].next = tmp;
        
    }

    struct timeval startTv, endTv;
    uint64_t scaled_iterations = iterations;

    gettimeofday(&startTv, NULL);

    cache_line current = cache_lines[0];
    uint32_t total = current.next;
    for(uint32_t n = 0; n < scaled_iterations; ++n) {
        current = cache_lines[current.next];
        total += current.next;
    }

    gettimeofday(&endTv, NULL);
    
    time_t time_diff_ms = 1e6 * (endTv.tv_sec - startTv.tv_sec) + (endTv.tv_usec - startTv.tv_usec);
    double latency = 1e3 * (double) time_diff_ms / (double) scaled_iterations;

    if (total == 0) printf("sum == 0 (?)\n");

    free(cache_lines);

    return latency;

}

#define ITERATIONS 100000000

int main() {
    std::cout << "CACHE_LINE_SIZE_BYTES: " << CACHE_LINE_SIZE_BYTES << std::endl;
    std::cout << "U64_PER_CACHE_LINE: " << U64_PER_CACHE_LINE << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of pointer: "  << sizeof(cache_line*) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of uint64_t: " << sizeof(uint64_t) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of cache_line struct: " << sizeof(cache_line) << std::endl;


    printf("Num. Cache lines,Latency (ns)\n");
    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(default_test_sizes) / sizeof(int); i++) {
        double result = runTest(default_test_sizes[i], ITERATIONS);
        printf("%d,%.5g\n", default_test_sizes[i], result);
    }

}


and on my CPU with following caches:
L1 size: 32kB,
L2 size: 256kB,
L3 size: 12MB.

I get the following:
CACHE_LINE_SIZE_BYTES: 64
U64_PER_CACHE_LINE: 8
Size of pointer: 8
Size of uint64_t: 8
Size of cache_line struct: 64
Num. Cache lines,Latency (ns)
2,3.3074
4,2.3374
8,2.3873
12,2.2797
16,2.2301
24,2.1864
32,2.2436
48,2.3232
64,2.2363
96,2.3279
128,2.0391
192,2.3194
256,2.1941
384,2.1234
512,2.1142
600,4.8127
768,4.2977
1024,4.7297
1536,4.4902
2048,4.558
3072,7.8019
4096,8.0671
5120,9.5193
6144,11.242
8192,13.565
10240,14.654
12288,14.989
16384,16.542
24567,16.561
32768,16.72
65536,19.067
98304,25.08
131072,50.754
196608,91.816
262144,111.06
393216,122.16
524288,120.96
1048576,127.99


In terms of cache lines that each cache can hold, we see some 'division' sizes:

512 lines: L1 cache limit,
4096 lines: L2 cache limit,
196608 lines: L3 cache limit.

But, I got several questions:

When all lines fit into L1, the access time is constant. And, as well, when they fit into L2, the access is constant.
Yet, when we go to L3, the access time is increasing. Is because the L3 is split into my 6 cores?
If I were to change the body of the loop to use the padding as well:

    for(uint32_t n = 0; n < scaled_iterations; ++n) {
        current = cache_lines[current.next];
        total += current.padding[0];
    }


The penalty would be only to add one L1 access, right?

If I wanted to measure only L2 access time (now is a distribution between L1 access time and L2 access time, I only have to read 512 cache lines, start measuring time, do the loop, and measure end time. How to ensure that the compiler doesn't remove the 512 cache lines readings since they might be not used?


Not sure of 2, but I can answer 1 and 3:
1: L3 latency increases with occupation rather than being constant - unless you are ensuring your code is the only one running (bare metal or maybe some real-time OS setup) then yes, the other threads will "pollute" (from your code's perspective) the cache and require extra reads from RAM when they cause your data to be evicted. Since L1 and L2 are local to the core on your system this is basically impossible during the execution of your code within its own thread, so those end up basically constant.
3: You can use assembly tricks to avoid optimizing away the unused reads, or you can mark the variable as volatile.
